# As civilization advances , will the divide between various income groups/economic classes reduce or widen?

Tags: political-philosophy

I was reading on post-scarcity abundance , and I saw in various sci-fi related themes that in some cases the gap widens and in some cases it reduces. I was also thinking whether this gap exists due to Darwinism . In natural animal tribes , the alpha/leader has more resources then the pack ,while similar happens in artificially created divisions in the society .

Comment: So far, it has widened, BUT in absolute terms, in most countries the people at the bottom side of that gap are still better off than they were before. The rising tide raised all ships, but it did raise the ships of the wealthy more apparently.

Comment: That depends on what society decides.

Comment: A strange anthropomorphism @NotThatGuy. Especially in an age when a Putin who starts a war (at least ostensibly) with hundreds of thousands of deaths on both sides wins a "landslide victory". Whereas the country that is the paragon of Freedom and Democracy seems unable to find any better than the top two geriatric contenders out of 300 million people. Assuming  people actually choose what they seem to choose really doesnt make sense

Comment: @Rushi "*In the land of the blind, the one eyed man is king.*" (or, President, as the case may be)

Comment: @Rushi I don't see why it's a strange anthropomorphism. The collective decisions of members of society will determine what happens, regardless of why those people make those decisions and regardless of how many are acting irrationally or in ways that are contrary to the outcomes they may want, and regardless of which societal structures exist that may force people to make decisions they're unhappy with, and which people may tolerate due to cognitive biases or the limited power of individuals.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I'm trying to take in your statement... I guess it doesn't seem to me that society decides, that is: there is no decision maker, just a random process like a pachinko machine. It seems just as blind and unfixable as evolution in the animal realm. Can't we do better?

Comment: @ScottRowe The difference is that humans have the ability to relatively accurately predict consequences of our actions (even far-reaching consequences), the ability to change our actions in response to the predicted consequences, and the ability to work together to effect change. The question is less whether we're able to change the outcome, and more whether we'll choose to do so. We are a lot of distinct actors - that doesn't make it random, it just makes outcomes less dependent on the actions of any individual, and more reliant on collective action.

Comment: @NotThatGuy The word 'collective' has strong quantitive associations. For math it is a priori defined and fine: *The average of {7,3,5} is 5* Informally the the 7 pulls the same as the 3 and we get the same as (7+3+5)/3. In the case of physics its messier but only slightly: Think of the diff between the earth and a platonic sphere. The remarkable accuracy of {latitude,longitude,altitude} to pin down locations is wonderful given that the earth is not a perfect sphere.

Comment: ... But with humans what is your notion of "average"?? The purposive directed action of one Aaron Bushnell counteracts the lethargic selfish inaction of exactly how many others? 1000? 8 billion? 754678.32? You may not realize it but you belong to the "religion of democracy" I too do but not so devoutly [see Churchill](https://winstonchurchill.org/resources/quotes/the-worst-form-of-government/). You believe that one-person-one-vote works. I see that most people are easily bribable. And produces a well oiled plutocracy masquerading as democracy

Comment: @ScottRowe See . Thats why as I [say](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/110697/37256) economics is the right take on this not politics nor technology

Comment: @NotThatGuy ok, but I think politicians in general do not have the human abilities you listed. Perhaps many people do not? I'm not an actor, I'm a programmer. It seems like actors are causing a lot of trouble these days, especially the bad ones. Maybe a UBI would help. But politicians will never agree to that, because we would realize that they are not earning their keep. Looking at Brownian Motion, the result of generalized collective action seems to be dispersion. It might be better if things were more uniform... We will probably find out, if I live that long.

Comment: @Rushi I never used the word "average", and I never said that democracies work perfectly or that people aren't flawed (on the contrary, I said the exact opposite).

Comment: @ScottRowe Politicians (at least in the US) have the ability to do what's best for the country, but aren't really incentivised to do so. They have greater incentive to appease certain groups of voters and donors. The general public has the ability to change that, to hold politicians accountable, to replace them, to change the political system, but that would require a lot of collaboration, and at the moment there's too much disagreement between the left and the right, and many people may not see, nor be able to agree on, a better solution. Although getting 1 law (like UBI) passed is easier.

Comment: @NotThatGuy ok, well, not to drag on, but we can't even agree to allow not doing the time change twice a year, and even the 'experts' are divided equally on whether std time or dst is 'healthier' for people, not to mention children going to school in the dark (so move the start time of school one hour? Are we completely helpless here?!?) I think that humans are NOT able to govern themselves. Would be nice to be proven wrong there.

Comment: @ScottRowe Things do change, it just sometimes takes a while, and it's easy to want large-scale change but not see much happening for days, weeks, months, and years, and then feel like change is basically impossible. But we make small changes (and, less commonly, big changes), such that the world looked very different a few decades ago. Change happens too slowly, but it does happen. Although not all changes are improvements.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in a society where more wealth also gives you more influence and less wealth gives you less influence then this is inherently unstable: the one with more wealth will use their influence to change the rules of the game to get even more wealth and so on. So you have a vicious circle.

This will make a few very wealth. In theory if you live in a democracy this should balance the vicious circle: The majority would at some point counter act the accumulation. But as we can see this is currently not working at all.

From a Marxist point of view there are 2 processes that lead to inequality in a capitalist society:

- Capital **accumulation**: Those who can only sell their labor power and then get paid just enough to cover their living expenses can not accumulate wealth. Those who own more than what they need can use it to own means of production and thus let others work for them and use the surplus value to increase their wealth.
- **Concentration** of capital: This is where capitalists compete. If one makes a bad decision or has some bad luck he goes out of business and those with enough capital in their hand will buy up their factories. Thus capital tends towards concentration in fewer and fewer hands.

I would not use the term "Darwinism", as it would suggest that the "better" wins, when clearly it is mostly a game of luck. If you happen to be born with rich parents your and if you happen to be lucky enough to pick some good managers for your portfolio you can make a fortune while still being an idiot and in general it helps if you are just ruthless.

I would say that we would already be in a "post-scarcity" society, if it where not for the fact that capitalism has a tendency to create artificial scarcity. If you have an abundance of something then this will drive down prices. So there is always an incentive to create artificial scarcity. We see this in a lot of places. E.g. marketing and advertising tries to manipulate us into buying things we do not need.  Or think of "defense":

> "Once weapons were manufactured to fight wars. Now wars are
> manufactured to sell weapons." -- Arundhati Roy

So the question of whether we will end up in a dystopian or an utopian future is still open. If enough people realize that the current system is inadequate and dangerous then there is some hope.

Comment: I think many people realize, but can't see a better option than just trying to stay afloat in the storm. I also wonder whether ads and marketing have any influence, I've been hearing this for decades, but do people actually notice them? Maybe it is just correlation: there happen to be ads for things people happen to 'want', but no causation? Maybe their peers and circumstances influence them much more than electronic blaring.

Answer (score 1):

**Erasmus Journal for Philosophy and Economics,
Volume 11, Issue 2,
Autumn 2018, pp. 163-190.**

Do People Deserve their Economic Rents?
THOMAS MULLIGAN
Georgetown University

https://philarchive.org/archive/MULDPD-3

> Abstract: Rather than answering the broad question, ‘What is a just
> income?’, in this essay I consider one component of income—economic
> rent—under one understanding of justice—as giving people what they
> deserve. As it turns out, the answer to this more focused question is
> ‘no’. People do not deserve their economic rents, and there is no bar of
> justice to their confiscation. After briefly covering the concept of desert
> and explaining what economic rents are, I analyze six types of rent and
> show that each is unjustified from the point of view of desert. I
> conclude by drawing some political and economic lessons from the
> preceding analysis, and by describing how these considerations can
> create a more just and efficient economy.

Comment: It would be better if people were doing things they really want to do instead of just working to prevent economic disaster for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This question, though phrased in terms of technology, is best answered in terms of economics. Not technology nor the diametrically opposite frame of politics.

I asked Google-Gemini for a summary of Thomas Piketty's ideas.
Some of my own brief comments are inline

> Here are the main ideas of Thomas Piketty, a French economist known for his work on wealth inequality:
>
> ### Central Thesis
>
> #### r > g
>
> This formula, where "r" represents the rate of return on capital (investments) and "g" represents the rate of economic growth, is central to Piketty's theory. He argues that in developed economies, the return on capital (r) tends to be consistently higher than the rate of economic growth (g) over the long term.
>
> ### Consequences of r > g
>
> #### Wealth Concentration
>
> When r > g, wealth tends to accumulate faster through inheritance and investment returns than it can be diluted through economic growth. This leads to a concentration of wealth at the top of the income distribution.
>
> #### Return to the "Patrimonial Capitalism" of the Past
>
> Piketty argues that if left unchecked, r > g can lead back to a system resembling the "patrimonial capitalism" of the past, where wealth and power are inherited and perpetuated across generations.
>
> ### Policy Solutions
>
> #### Progressive Wealth Tax
>
> Piketty proposes a progressive wealth tax as a solution to address rising inequality. This tax would levy a higher rate on individuals with greater wealth, aiming to redistribute wealth and slow down its concentration.
>
> #### Global Cooperation
>
> He emphasizes the need for global cooperation on wealth taxes to prevent wealthy individuals from simply moving their assets to countries with lower tax rates.

Heh! You must be joking... Just look at the wars!

> ### Criticisms
>
> #### Feasibility of Wealth Tax
>
> Some economists criticize the practicality of implementing a progressive wealth tax due to challenges in valuation and potential disincentives to investment.

Excuses... Excuses... Excuses

> #### Future Economic Growth
>
> Others argue that Piketty might underestimate the potential for future technological advancements to boost economic growth (g), which could counteract the r > g effect.

Ask the twitter users of Africa how much Elon shares

> ### Summary
>
> Piketty's work has sparked a global conversation about wealth inequality and potential solutions. His ideas continue to influence economic policy debates and inspire research on wealth distribution.

## Alternatives

I chose Piketty because he's the best economist (I know) for this.

If you want the opposite view there are others like Steven Pinker who believes everything is getting hunkier and dorier.

I consider him selective and dishonest so will not quote his ideas

Comment: Pinker is interesting and wildly optimistic, but I read something in one of his books that put me off, so I stopped reading him.

Comment: @ScottRowe Professionally: Pinker is a monolingual linguist. That's as much an oxymoron as a blind artist or deaf musician! [Yeah Beethoven was deaf; he became progressively deaf **after** being an accomplished musician] On more general political, human matters... Less said the better about Pinker and his "humanity"

Comment: At least I know lots of programming languages. That helps me talk with people about solving such problems. I try not to inject hideously violent and disturbing sub-stories In the things I write, like Mr. Pinker did. They seem to counter his own contention that things are improving.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is still a general unit of purchase called money, there is no doubt. While this can be successfully implemented in an exemplary model of socialist society, money itself brings hunger. A highly organized economic order indicates that there are only poor people who espouse certain ideologies. The fact that the national security level of countries such as Chile and Kuwait is quite high is in parallel with the values of their currencies. And this does not mean that there are no poor societies or that the domestic crime rate is close to 0, it just that the fact that other states have builded a production-consumption cycle that they have not yet done may indicate the existence of poor communities that prefer to be suppressed with a high crime rate.

Comment: Hi, please would you try to make points in a simpler way that sounds less self-contradictory? I keep thinking you say things I would like to hear, but I find the wording confusing.

Comment: @ScottRowe If there is money, there is greed. Systems theorists have not been able to understand this for a long time. The guaranteed solution to the economic order is to remove money from circulation.

Comment: I would say, if there is ignorance and / or needless scarcity, there is greed. But curing ignorance and scarcity would reduce the need for money systems.

Comment: @ScottRowe and due to the weakening of the attachment to money, persons can spend more on luxury necessities. But more than that, they will see this wealth as a privilege. It can be thought that this problem can be solved with the restoration of society. Since it does not provide successful security of supply-demand, this whole system can be disorganized by SJWs in a management/secular change. Not getting the luxury with money is the peak point of luxury living.